# regex for validating only alphanumeric characters full stop, comma, colon, and semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric

I am very new to regex and JavaScript.

I need a  regex for validate only alphanumeric characters and full stop (.), comma(,), colon(:), and semicolon(;).

Comment: This really isn't a question. You should first learn the language basics, including some regular expression basics, give it a try and ask a question if you get stuck somewhere specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to verify that the complete line contains only the allowed characters:

`var regexp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,:;]+$/);`

`^` matches at the beginning of the line

`[]` matches one of the surrounded characters

`+` makes the previous element one or more times

`$` matches the end of the line

If the string is allowed to be empty, then turn the `+` into a `*`

Comment: Thanks so much, This help me a lot, especially for the use of (*) or (+).
I need to validate a String with characters repeated no more that a specific number, for example 2. I think in /^[a-z]{0,2}$/ but i miss something.

Comment: The {0,2} part is correct. Your regex matches strings of length 0, 1 or 2, consisting only of lower case letters. You might want to show us some example string that you want to match (or exclude). BTW: for thanking you can mark the answer as the accepted ;-)